# Weird meta data from Wordpress import?

Tags: jekyll

I imported all of my content from Wordpress, and it looks 90% good, but it pulled in some meta data that I don't THINK I need. It's at the top of every post. Safe to delete?

```
meta:
  _wpcom_is_markdown: '1'
  _edit_last: '1'
  _wpas_done_all: '1'
author:
  login: taylor
  email: taylor.a.huston@gmail.com
  display_name: taylor
  first_name: ''
  last_name: ''
excerpt: !ruby/object:Hpricot::Doc
  options: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don´t you just hide the meta data in you template?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Metadata_API

Comment: I've already exported it from WP and imported it into my Jekyll blog. I don't have that many posts it would only take a second to remove it from all of them, I just wanted to make sure it wasn't important before I did. Still relatively new to Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in your `_layouts` and `_includes` folders. If they don't make use of tags like `page.meta.something` or `page.author.something` you can remove them.

Answer (score 0):

The `_wp_com_markdown` and `_wpas_all_done` are from Jetpack. They are respectively tied to the Markdown and Publicize modules. Deleting `_wpas_all_done` would likely result in the Publicize module resharing the post to all connected social media accounts the next time it was saved.